# Laravel eloquent query using two relations

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, laravel-5.7

I have next db structure - product can be in many categories, product can be in many markets. Models `\App\Product`, `\App\Market` and `\App\Category` are created with many to many relations - `belongsToMany()`.

[image]

```
class Product extends Model
{
    public function categories()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany('App\Category');
    }

    public function markets()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany('App\Market');
    }
}

class Category extends Model
{
    public function products()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany('App\Product');
    }
}

class Market extends Model
{
    public function products()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany('App\Product');
    }
}
```

In `route.web` I get category to display products

```
Route::get('/catalog/{current_category?}', 'CatalogController@index')->name('catalog.index');
```

Current market I can get from session (user select market when open website)

```
$market = $request->session()->get('market'); // or Session::get('market');
// $market->id
// $market->slug
```

In my `MarketController@index` I want to get all products for category from route and for current market from session. But how can I do it? I can get category products and market products. But how can I get category and market products at the same time?

```
public function index(Request $request, Category $current_category = null)
{
    if ($current_category) {

        $market_id = $request->session()->get('market')->id;

        $products = $current_category->products;
        // ...
    }
}
```

Comment: Share your models so we could see the relationships.

Comment: @MyLibary update question

Comment: What you have there is good candidate for [manyToMany polymorphic](https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/eloquent-relationships#many-to-many-polymorphic-relations) relationship. Your products should be tags from example.

Comment: @Tpojka can you show in answers, how can I use it?

Comment: @autumnrustle Added.

Answer (score 2):

If you want product based on category , use below query:

```
$products = $current_category->products()->get();
```

If you want products based on market, first you need to get market object than you can get products based on it.

```
$market =  Market::find($market_id);
$market_products = $market->products()->get();
```

If you want products based on market and category you can use below query.

```
$products = Product::whereHas('categories', function($q) {
                        $q->where('category_id', $current_category->id);
                     })
                     ->whereHas('markets', function($q) {
                        $q->where('market_id', $market_id);
                     })
                     ->get();
```

Answer (score 0):

As pointed in comment, you can achieve it with many to many polymorphic relation

- tables structure

```
categories
    id - integer
    name - string

markets
    id - integer
    name - string

products
    id - integer
    name - string

productables
    product_id - integer
    productable_id - integer
    productable_type - string
```

- Category model

```
<?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Category extends Model
{
    /**
     * Get all of the products for the category.
     */
    public function products()
    {
        return $this->morphToMany('App\Product', 'productable');
    }
}
```

- Market model

```
<?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Market extends Model
{
    /**
     * Get all of the products for the market.
     */
    public function products()
    {
        return $this->morphToMany('App\Product', 'productable');
    }
}
```

- Product model

```
<?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Product extends Model
{
    /**
     * Get all of the categories that are assigned this product.
     */
    public function categories()
    {
        return $this->morphedByMany('App\Category', 'productable');
    }

    /**
     * Get all of the markets that are assigned this product.
     */
    public function markets()
    {
        return $this->morphedByMany('App\Market', 'productable');
    }
}
```

Than you can get products belonging to both (certain category and certain market) with

```
$products = \App\Product::where(['productable_id' => $category->id, 'productable_type' => get_class($category)])->orWhere(['productable_id' => $market->id, 'productable_type' => get_class($market)])->get();
```

assuming from your question that category and market  are already known.

@YasinPatel 's solution should work too, but this way your DB architecture is more flexible. It's up to you now. Study about polymorphic relations solutions, you could find it interesting.